# ImportError: libcublas.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am having a huge troube to run this in my code. I already tried to reinstall the packges, install in the environment etc, but I don't think I'm doing it correctly.

```
import keras 
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense"
```

I get this message:

> Using TensorFlow backend.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       import keras
>
> File "/home/wagner/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/**init**.py", line 3, in 
>       from . import utils
>
> File "/home/wagner/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/utils/**init**.py", line 6, in 
>       from . import conv_utils
>
> File "/home/wagner/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py", line 3, in 
>       from .. import backend as K
>
> File "/home/wagner/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/**init**.py", line 83, in 
>       from .tensorflow_backend import *
>
> File "/home/wagner/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 1, in 
>       import tensorflow as tf
>
> File "/home/wagner/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 24, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import *
>
> File "/home/wagner/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>
> File "/home/wagner/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 72, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg)
>
> ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/wagner/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>     File "/home/wagner/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>     File "/home/wagner/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>     File "/home/wagner/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>     File "/home/wagner/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec)
>   ImportError: libcublas.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Comment: Tensorflow-GPU needs Cuda 8.0 and CuDNN 6.0. Higher CuDNN versions can cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

What versions of TensorFlow, cuda and cudnn are you running?

Running the following command in the working directory solved the problem for me:

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/extras/CUPTI/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

But you will have to replace the `/usr/local/cuda-8.0/extras/CUPTI/lib64` with the relevant location on your machine.

Comment: I just installed cuda-8.0. How do I know the relvant location? I'm a beginner

Comment: /usr/local/cuda-8.0/extras/CUPTI/lib64

Comment: And what is in that directory? `ls /usr/local/cuda-8.0/extras/CUPTI/lib64`  

Have you restarted the computer after installing both TF and cuda?

Comment: Directory not found

Comment: I'll try to restart it, but I'm pretty sure I did it

Comment: Aha. What's in your `/usr/local/` directory?

Comment: bin  cuda  cuda-9.0  etc  games  include  lib  man  sbin  share  src

Comment: It looks like you have cuda-9.0 installed, and not cuda-8.0

Comment: Shoukd I remove it? And reinstall cuda 8?

Comment: You can run cuda-8.0 and 9.0 side by side. You shouldn't have to uninstall 9.0.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Here's the link to cuda-8.0: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-80-ga2-download-archive

Then select the options that match your operating system

Comment: The download is taking a long time, but I'll try with it

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue?

If my suggestions helped then you can mark it as the answer so others will see this thread.

Comment: Technically, there was no question.